# What file extension do OpenOffice Dictionary files have?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice, file-extension, dictionary, texlive

I have a program that supports importing OpenOffice Dictionary files for use with its own spell checker, which I would like to do since the language I want to write in isn't available as a built-in language. However, when I click on "Import Dictionary…" the file picker only tells me that it wants me to pick an "OpenOffice Dictionary", but not what file extension it expects. As such, I would like to know, what file extension do OpenOffice Dictionary files typically have? If it's relevant, the program in question is TeXstudio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From
[OpenOffice Wiki - Extension Dictionaries](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Extension_Dictionaries) :

> Extensions should be created as oxt files and uploaded to the repository. Only that way checking for available updates will happen automatically.

Although I'm not using OpenOffice, the answer seems like : `.oxt`.